# How can I give my SF Customer Community users one-click import of their LinkedIn photo/bio?

Tags: community

I just posted this as a feature request on the SF IdeaExchange in the hopes that SF will make it part of the product going forward, but since that's going to take a long time, I'm hoping someone has already figured out how to do it using APEX and the LinkedIn API.  Any tips?

See my post in the IdeaExchange for a full description and screenshot mockups (and please vote for the idea while you are there!):  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5C0AAI

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Sam. You'd greatly improve the quality of your question by not only linking to content elsewhere, but copying it here. Also displaying what you've already tried or indicating the problems you've encountered will usually lead to more specific answers.

Comment: I feel like it'd be easy for an experienced developer with time. Unfortunately, my time is scarce.